# If $f(a)=a.m$ why $f$ is a surjective function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

About the following theorem:

[image]

I cannot understand Why $f$ is a surjective function?

Naively speaking, since for any $a.m$ there is an $a\in R$ so we are done! But the set $M'={\{a.m \ | \ a\in R \ , \ m\in M  }\}$ may or maynot equal to $M$. For example, define $f(a)=0$ for any $a\in R$ and still $Im(M) \cong R/Ann(<m>)$ holds but now $Im(M) \ne M$ if $m \ne 0$.

Comment: I may be a little rusty on this topic, but the proposition requires that $\langle m \rangle$ is a cyclic $R$-module. In that case could it be true that $am = 0$ for all $a\in R$?

Comment: A cyclic module $M = \langle m\rangle$ means that $f$ is surjective by definition.

Comment: @DavidK I cant understand why not possible that am=0 for all a∈R even if <m> is a cyclic R-module ? Thank you

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan. Sorry I dont understand why.

Comment: @Edi: By definition, $\langle m\rangle = \{am : a\in R\}$

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan. Ha! I thought $\langle m\rangle $ ıs a group cyclic. Thanks

Comment: @DavidK This is possible, but you'd have to be working with rings not having unity. Typically the requirement that $1\cdot m=m$ prevents the annihilator from consuming the whole ring.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $M$ is generated by the element $m$ i.e $M=<m>=\{a.m : a\in R\}$. When you define the function $f:R\rightarrow M$ you send each element $a\in R$ to $a.m$ the image of all the elements of $R$ is the set $M$, so f is surjective.

Besides, $ker(f)=\{a\in R : f(a)=0\}=\{a \in R : a.m=0\}=Ann(m).$ As $f$ is homomorphism (it´s evident) you have than by the first isomorphism theorem : $ R/ker(f)=R/Ann(m)\simeq M=Im(f)$